# Getting first index of each list in a nested list in Kotlin

Tags: android, list, kotlin

I'm retrieving a list of lists from an API in JSON. This is how the response looks like.

```
{
    "result":"success",
    "documentation":"https://www.exchangerate-api.com/docs",
    "terms_of_use":"https://www.exchangerate-api.com/terms"
    "supported_codes":[
        ["AED","UAE Dirham"],
        ["AFN","Afghan Afghani"],
        ["ALL","Albanian Lek"],
        ["AMD","Armenian Dram"],
        ["ANG","Netherlands Antillian Guilder"],
        ["AOA","Angolan Kwanza"],
        ["ARS","Argentine Peso"],
        ["AUD","Australian Dollar"],
        ["AWG","Aruban Florin"],
        ["AZN","Azerbaijani Manat"],
        ["BAM","Bosnia and Herzegovina Convertible Mark"],
        ["BBD","Barbados Dollar"] etc. etc.
    ]
}
```

And this is the data class

```
data class CurrencyResponse(
    @Json(name="documentation") val documentation: String,
    @Json(name="result")  val result: String,
    @Json(name="supported_codes") val supported_codes: List<List<String>>,
    @Json(name="terms_of_use") val terms_of_use: String
)
```

I managed to get the list of lists(supported_codes) but what I want now is to get the first index of each list(AED,AFN,ALL,etc.) and store them in a list, convert it to an array, then use that array to populate my spinners. Can anyone help me out with that?

Below is the relevant code.

Thank you.

CurrencyRepository.kt

```
package com.example.currencyconverter.data

import com.example.currencyconverter.BuildConfig
import javax.inject.Inject
import javax.inject.Singleton


@Singleton
class CurrencyRepository @Inject constructor(private val currencyApi: CurrencyApi) {
    suspend fun getConversionRate(baseCurrency: String, toCurrency: String, amount: Double?): ConversionResponse {
       return currencyApi.convert(BuildConfig.API_KEY, baseCurrency, toCurrency, amount)
    }
    suspend fun getCurrencies(): List<String> {
        return currencyApi.getCurrencies(BuildConfig.API_KEY).supported_codes
    }


}
```

CurrencyViewModel.kt

```
package com.example.currencyconverter.ui

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import com.example.currencyconverter.data.CurrencyRepository
import dagger.hilt.android.lifecycle.HiltViewModel
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import javax.inject.Inject


@HiltViewModel
class CurrencyViewModel @Inject constructor(private val repository: CurrencyRepository): ViewModel() {

    private val _conversionResult = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val conversionResult: LiveData<String> = _conversionResult
    private val _currencies = MutableLiveData<List<String>>()
    val currencies: LiveData<List<String>> = _currencies

    init {
        getCurrencies()
    }

fun getConversionRate(baseCurrency: String, toCurrency: String, amount: Double?)  {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        _conversionResult.value = repository.getConversionRate(baseCurrency, toCurrency, amount).conversion_result
    }
}
    fun getCurrencies() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _currencies.value = repository.getCurrencies()
        }
    }


}
```

HomeFragment.kt

```
package com.example.currencyconverter.ui

import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.MotionEvent
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager
import android.widget.AdapterView
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.viewModels
import com.example.currencyconverter.R
import com.example.currencyconverter.databinding.FragmentHomeBinding
import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint

@AndroidEntryPoint
class HomeFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_home) {
    private val viewModel by viewModels<CurrencyViewModel>()
    private var _binding: FragmentHomeBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
    }


    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        _binding = FragmentHomeBinding.bind(view)
        lateinit var firstCurrency: String
        lateinit var secondCurrency: String
        

        viewModel.currencies.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            binding.list.text = " ${it[0]} , ${it[1]} "
        }

       var currenciesFormat = arrayOf(viewModel.currencies.value?.get(0),
            viewModel.currencies.value?.get(1)
        )




        binding.apply {
                spinnerFirst.adapter = ArrayAdapter(requireContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, currenciesFormat)
                spinnerFirst.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
                    override fun onItemSelected(
                        adapterView: AdapterView<*>?,
                        view: View?,
                        position: Int,
                        id: Long
                    ) {
                        firstCurrency = adapterView?.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()

                    }

                    override fun onNothingSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?) {
                    }
                }

            spinnerSecond.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
                override fun onItemSelected(
                    adapterView: AdapterView<*>?,
                    view: View?,
                    position: Int,
                    id: Long
                ) {
                    secondCurrency = adapterView?.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()


                }

                override fun onNothingSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?) {
                }


            }
        }

        binding.constraintLayout.setOnTouchListener(object : View.OnTouchListener {
            override fun onTouch(p0: View?, p1: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
                closeKeyboard(p0)
                return true
            }


        })

        binding.button.setOnClickListener {
            val stringInTextField = binding.amountText.text.toString()
            val amount = stringInTextField.toDoubleOrNull()
            if (amount == null) {
                binding.resultText.text = " "
            }
            closeKeyboard(binding.amountText)
            viewModel.getConversionRate(firstCurrency, secondCurrency, amount)
            viewModel.conversionResult.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
                binding.resultText.text = it
            }
        }


    }

    private fun closeKeyboard(view: View?) {
        val imm =
            view?.context?.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        if (view != null) {
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Avoid adding unnecessary/irrelevant code when asking question. Keep focus on the issue. Here's how to [create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: To use a `List<CurrencyResponse>` to get a `List<String>` holding the first codes you can use `currencyResponseList.map { it.supported_codes.first() }`. You don't need to convert to an array to use it with a Spinner.

Comment: Don't use Double to represent currency amounts. Use BigDecimal.

Comment: Will do! Thank you guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `kotlin.collections`'s `map` function. https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map.html

```
fun main(){
    val supportedCodes = listOf(
        listOf("AED","UAE Dirham"),
        listOf("AFN","Afghan Afghani"),
        listOf("ALL","Albanian Lek")
    )

    val codes = supportedCodes.map { it[0] }
    println(codes)
}
```

The output is a list containing just the first element from each nested list.

```
[AED, AFN, ALL]
```

Comment: Or you could use ``it.first()`` if you like (or ``firstOrNull`` so you can handle missing stuff safely if this is coming from THE INTERNET). And you can stick ``.toTypedArray()`` on the end to convert it from a list